# flex/as3 - How to force BitmapData smooth not to draw

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, bitmapdata, smoothing

I'm gonna force a `BitmapData` smooth.

but I can't do `BitmapData.draw()` because the performance of application.

If I draw Bitmap, the application slow down to next step.
(this is on flex mobile)

so I need how to force bitmapData smooth without redraw bitmapData.

(also, I can't use `Bitmap(bitmapData).smoothing`)

what can I do for this?

Comment: try using texture and gpu rendering, look for [starling framework](https://www.google.com/search?q=as3+starling+smooth+texture)

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming the only way to smooth the pixels in a bitmapData is by re-drawing the `bitmap` container with the smoothing boolean set to true in [**`BitmapData.Draw()`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()).

Solution is to set [**`smoothing`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#smoothing) on the container `Bitmap` object itself, not the internal `bitmapData`. Later you can always update the bitmapData but the Bitmap object will always be smoothed.

Logic is something like below :

```
var myBMPData : BitmapData = new BitmapData(320, 240);
myBMPData.draw( someThing ); //just draw, no smoothing here for BitmapData

var myBMP : Bitmap = new Bitmap( myBitmapData );
myBMP.smoothing = true; //use smoothing on Bitmap that holds bitmapData

addChild(myBMP);
```

Comment: No you said you can't use (quote) `Bitmap(bitmapData).smoothing` which is still targeting the bitmapData itself. If BMPdata is 100w x 100h then you force CPU to handle 10 000 items (pixels). I suggest `Bitmap.smoothing` which targets only 1 item for CPU effort and no `draw`ing is involved. Seems strange but that's how it is... I see it even in 3D graphics software (1 million polys selected for moving = slow VS 1 group object containing same millions of polys = fast). So **smooth the container** not the individual pixels (bitmapdata). The visual effect result is same.

Comment: Show example code of **how to re-create your issue**... Is there a technical reason or limitation why you can't use `Bitmap.smoothing` at all? Otherwise you gotta write your own bi-linear filter for smoothing. Try using some gpu-based [**Pixel Bender smoother**](http://www.smart-page.net/blog/2010/02/21/smartaa-reconstruct-anti-aliasing-with-pixel-bender/) code in your AS3 project. Check online tutorials how to import PBJ to use as `=new shader()` object within AS3 code. That's just one example anyways.